# Mac splitscreen (not dual display)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I have a Macbook Pro 2012, and I want to split the display in two. I don't want to set up a dual display though. I want a cloned desktop on the same screen, so that it's the same image on both sides. I've searched for how to do this, but keep coming up with links to dual displays.

I'm trying to do this, because I have a large mask that obscures my vision (think Deadmau5), and I want to feed the laptop into a small HDMI display inside the mask. I am already doing this with a Raspberry Pi with Camera, and splitting the camera signal in two. I have Google Goggles inside to focus the image so close to my face.

Is there a program that can accomplish this? It would be great if it could just split the screen on the small HDMI display, but not necessary.

[image: Macbook Pro Splitscreen]

Comment: just to clarify, Apple Split View does not work for you ?

Comment: Apple Split View is only for using two different applications (as far as I know). I need to see the same application on both sides.

Comment: Hi. Just use the contact us section at the bottom of this (every page) and link to the posts and accounts that need to be merged.

Comment: Reminder, anyone can suggest an edit to the question to clarify it once comments ask for clarifications.